# RabbitMq anti-starvation pattern

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

**The problem to solve:** Prevent a customer from starving other customers.

I plan for every customer to have their own queue and then one *Consumer* consuming from all those queues. In my case there could be hundreds of customers, but queues are cheap. Having a reasonable low [prefetch count](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) the default broker behavior ([to randomly select which queue to pop from](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/src/rabbit_limiter.erl#L433)) should yield a satisfying result.

[image]

The issue with this strategy is when a *new customer* comes along. I can lazily create the queue and bind it to the exchange `msg.in` in the *Publisher*. But how do I get the *Consumer* to consume from this new `customer.xxx` queue?

It's almost the [Topics pattern](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-dotnet.html), but not really since I need a buffer per client. Nor can this be solved with [Priority](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) which will screw up the per customer message order. Is there a way to consume based on a pattern? Like there is for binding, eg. `customer.*`.

Polling the [management API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api) is an option, but will delay the processing of the first message of a new customer until the *Consumer* have polled. Having a separate [pub/sub](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html) channel for meta-data like `new customer.003` that the *Consumer* could act upon would reduce the latency (and avoid polling the API), but will make the *Publisher* more complex.

I've a feeling there's a nice solution out there, I just haven't been able to find it yet. Thankful for your feedback!

Comment: Is there a reason to have all these separate queues that are being consumed from instead of just one that all the clients publish to?

Comment: I've edited the question to rename client to customer to clarify. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence `... when a new customer comes along. I can lazily create the queue and bind it ...`. Could you, at the same time, notify the consumer a new queue has been created?

Comment: The queue creation and binding is idempotent so a publisher could always make sure the queue exists by simply create it every time. Performance wise this is not optimal, but that's what I meant. A better solution might be to publish with the mandatory flag set and, in case the was no customer queue bound, create it and also send a notification on the pub/sub meta channel I elaborated a bit on.

Comment: Almost 3 years later, have you found a good solution to this?

Comment: I have not, but it's still relevant. One alternative might be to have a priority queue combined with some throttling aware publishers that changes a customers priority depending on e.g. messages/s.